# PHP parse HTML tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I'm pretty new to PHP.
I have the text of a body tag of some page in a string variable.
I'd like to know if it contains some tag ... where the tag name tag1 is given, and if so, take only that tag from the string.
How can I do that simply in PHP?

Thanks!!

Comment: There are several ways to approach that and they all depend on what exactly you want to do. Do you need to *parse* HTML? Use an HTML parser. Do you want to strip tags and the syntax is known to be within certain limits? Use `strip_tags()`. Do you want to blacklist certain tags in arbitrary HTML? Maybe better think about *whitelisting* allowed tags instead? Use a library like HTML Purifier.

Comment: @Troy If my anwser helped please accept it so others can learn form it. If not how can i help you further?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would be looking at something like this:

```
<?php
$content = "";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("example.html");
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tag1');
if(count($items) > 0) //Only if tag1 items are found 
{
    foreach ($items as $tag1)
    {
         // Do something with $tag1->nodeValue and save your modifications
         $content .= $tag1->nodeValue;
    }
}
else
{
     $content = $doc->saveHTML();
}
echo $content;
?>
```

[DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) represents an entire HTML or XML document; serves as the root of the document tree. So you will have a valid markup, and by finding elements By Tag Name you won't find comments.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is regex.

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all('#<li.*?>(.*?)</li>#', 'abc', $matches);
```

`$matches[0][x]` contains the whole matches such as `<li class="small">list entry</li>`, `$matches[1][x]` containt the inner HTML only such as `list entry`.

Answer (score -1):

Fast way:

Look for the index position of tag1 then look for the index position of /tag1. Then cut the string between those two indexes. Look up strpos and substr on php.net
Also this might not work if your string is too long.

```
$pos1 = strpos($bigString, '<tag1>');
$pos2 = strpos($bigString, '</tag1>');
$resultingString = substr($bigString, -$pos1, $pos2);
```

You might have to add and/or substract some units from $pos1 and $pos2 to get the $resultingString right.
(if you don't have comments with tag1 inside of them *sigh*)

The right way:

Look up html parsers

Comment: And how do you look up the positions of the tags? Keep in mind that this is valid HTML: `<!-- <tag> --><foo bar="</tag>">`...

Comment: $pos1 = strpos($bigString, '<tag1>'); Doesn't matter, you treat it as a string.

Comment: Ooops, you just found "<tag1>" inside `<!-- <tag1> -->`, i.e. not really a tag... :)

Comment: interesting! Then I would take all the comments, generate an unique string, place it instead of the comments, and in my $resultingString, I would put them back in. Ooops, I just found a solution :)

Comment: Or you could, you know, just use a proper *HTML parser*. :P

Comment: hey, I did mention that as "the right way" in my answer

Comment: Fair enough. Just wondering why you also mention the wrong way. ;)

Comment: Because, it exists. It's like a rubic cube, you can always, you know, take it all apart and assemble it already solved.. if that was your purpose in the first place.

Comment: hi, thank you all. i have a string without the whole html, just the body tag extracted from it by `                                                $html = file_get_html($link); 
foreach($html->find('body') as $element)`. now, i'd like to take an inner tag (which might have properties) called tag1, but only if it exists. otherwise, i'd like the body tag as before.

Comment: $html = file_get_html($link);
$content = "";
foreach($html->find('body') as $element) $content .= $element->text();