# PHP curl. Traversing search results

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am working on a website that allows people to search for an 'x' product and display the results in a table format for example.

I am planning on scraping the search data from another website using php curl. (the owner of the website being scraped is aware and allows it, so no legal issues there).

I already have a php curl code to go and login to the website, and do a search based on user inputs. I have no idea how to go thru the results of the search and output then in my website one by one.

PHP curl code:

```
$username = '********';
$password = '********';
$loginUrl = 'http://www.a-website.com/login.asp';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&submit1=' . 'Login');

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie stuff hure');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

/*         * *****************SEARCH HERE****************** */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.a-website.com/Index.asp');
//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);


//Set the post parameters

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'search_txt_vs=' . '' . '&search_txt_UPC=' . '' . '&search_txt_Name=' . $searchString .
        '&search_txt_Manufacturer=' . '' . '&submit=' . 'Search');
//execute the request (the search)
$Search = curl_exec($ch);

print CJSON::encode($Search);
print $Search;

//save the data to disk
print $content;
```

Here is the html code from the website Im scrapping (which btw is in old school table format)

```
<td colspan="3" height="100%" valign="top">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#99CCCC" class="text">
        <tbody>
            <tr bgcolor="#9999CC">
                <td align="right" class="calendar">Sort &gt;</td>
                <td align="center"> <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=1">NDC</a>
                </td>
                <td align="left">   <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=2">Brand Name</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"> <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=3">Strength</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;   <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=4">UD</a>
                </td>
                <td align="left">   <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=5">Stock</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center"> <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=6">Manufacturer</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="cccccc">    <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=7">AWP</a>
&nbsp;/&nbsp;   <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=8">Your Price</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#9999CC">
                <td align="right" class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="center"> <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=9">UPC</a>
                </td>
                <td align="left">   <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=10">Generic Alt/Name</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"> <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=11">Size</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;   <a href="Index.asp?search_txt_UPC=&amp;search_txt_Name=novolin&amp;search_txt_Manufacturer=&amp;orderby=12">Form</a>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="3" class="selected">Category</td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="eeeeee">
                <td align="center" valign="top" rowspan="2">1
                    <br>    <a href="#" onclick="return openCart(19112,0.01021);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[add]</span></a>

                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">00169347718</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm_red">NOVOLIN 70/ 30U/ML CRT 5X3 ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 70-30 U/ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm">YES</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">NOVO NORDISK PHARM</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">$

    0.01&nbsp;

    &nbsp;/&nbsp;$

    0.01

    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="eeeeee">
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">000000000000</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm"><a href="#" onclick="return openGeneric('50101');">HUM INSULIN NPH/REG INSULIN HM</a></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 5X3ML </span>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="3"><span class="smallNorm">&nbsp;

    <a href="#" onclick="return openreturn(19112,0.01021);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[return]</span>
                    </a>INSULIN</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#99CCCC">
                <td align="center" valign="top" rowspan="2">2
                    <br>    <a href="#" onclick="return openCart(19116,0.012);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[add]</span></a>

                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">00169347418</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm_red">NOVOLIN N 100 UN/ML CRT 5X3 ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 100 U/ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm">YES</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">NNP</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">$

        0.00&nbsp;

    &nbsp;/&nbsp;$

    0.01

    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#99CCCC">
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">000000000000</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm"><a href="#" onclick="return openGeneric('05331');">NPH HUMAN INSULIN ISOPHANE</a></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 5X3ML </span>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="3"><span class="smallNorm">&nbsp;

    <a href="#" onclick="return openreturn(19116,0.012);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[return]</span>
                    </a>INSULIN</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="eeeeee">
                <td align="center" valign="top" rowspan="2">3
                    <br>    <a href="#" onclick="return openCart(45211,0.012);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[add]</span></a>

                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">00169231721</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm_red">NOVOLIN INNO 70/30 PFS 5X3 ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 70-30 U/ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm">YES</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">NOVO NORDISK PHARM</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">$


        0.00&nbsp;

    &nbsp;/&nbsp;$

    0.01

    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="eeeeee">
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">000000000000</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm"><a href="#" onclick="return openGeneric('24486');">HUM INSULIN NPH/REG INSULIN HM</a></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 5X3ML </span>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="3"><span class="smallNorm">&nbsp;

    <a href="#" onclick="return openreturn(45211,0.012);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[return]</span>
                    </a>INSULIN</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#99CCCC">
                <td align="center" valign="top" rowspan="2">4
                    <br>    <a href="#" onclick="return openCart(19117,82.0884);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[add]</span></a>

                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">00169183311</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm_red">NOVOLIN R 100 UN/ML VL 10 ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 100 U/ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm">YES</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">NOVO NORDISK PHARM</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">$

    99.00&nbsp;

    &nbsp;/&nbsp;$

    82.09

    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#99CCCC">
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">000169183311</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm"><a href="#" onclick="return openGeneric('11642');">INSULIN REGULAR HUMAN</a></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 10ML </span>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="3"><span class="smallNorm">&nbsp;

    <a href="#" onclick="return openreturn(19117,82.0884);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[return]</span>
                    </a>INSULIN</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="eeeeee">
                <td align="center" valign="top" rowspan="2">5
                    <br>    <a href="#" onclick="return openCart(19110,82.0884);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[add]</span></a>

                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">00169183711</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm_red">NOVOLIN 70/ 30U/ML VL 10 ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 70-30 U/ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm">YES</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">NOVO NORDISK PHARM</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">$

    99.00&nbsp;

    &nbsp;/&nbsp;$

    82.09

    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="eeeeee">
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">000169183711</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm"><a href="#" onclick="return openGeneric('50001');">HUM INSULIN NPH/REG INSULIN HM</a></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 10ML </span>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="3"><span class="smallNorm">&nbsp;

    <a href="#" onclick="return openreturn(19110,82.0884);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[return]</span>
                    </a>INSULIN</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#99CCCC">
                <td align="center" valign="top" rowspan="2">6
                    <br>    <a href="#" onclick="return openCart(19114,82.0884);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[add]</span></a>

                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">00169183411</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm_red">NOVOLIN N 100 UN/ML VL 10 ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 100 U/ML</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm">YES</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">NOVO NORDISK PHARM</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">$

    99.00&nbsp;

    &nbsp;/&nbsp;$

    82.09

    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#99CCCC">
                <td align="center"><span class="smallNorm">000000000000</span>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><span class="smallNorm"><a href="#" onclick="return openGeneric('11660');">NPH HUMAN INSULIN ISOPHANE</a></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="smallNorm"> 10ML </span>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="3"><span class="smallNorm">&nbsp;

    <a href="#" onclick="return openreturn(19114,82.0884);"><span class="smallNorm_red">[return]</span>
                    </a>INSULIN</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the string to a DOMDocument and use the getElementsByTagName and then write them into an array or something you can use. More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Also, similar question was answered here, considering you're returning HTML:[PHP parse HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458133/php-parse-html-tags)

Comment: hey thank you for your answer first of all. But can you be a little more specific? Perhaps an example. My main problem is that the output does not have any tag names. It is just tables inside tables inside tables. So how do I differentiate between the rest of the website and the actual items I want to display?