# how to separate selected tags from html content

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, strip-tags

I have an html like

```
 <span class="address">
   <h1>Dr. Maria Steffens</h1>
   <h4>Institute of Medico</h4>
   <h4></h4>
   <h4></h4>
   <p>Sta. Ana, strt PH-501</p>
   <p>1062 Caracas</p>
   <p>France</p>
  <br>
   <p>Telefon: +58-457-2889567</p>
   <p><a href="mailto:plasticsurgery@yahoo.com">plasticsurgery@yahoo.com</a></p>
   <p><a href="http://">www.mysite.com</a></p>
</span>
```

Now i want to separate every tag like

```
<h1>Dr. Maria Steffens</h1>
```

or occurrence of

```
<h4></h4> tag
```

**I have tried**

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.sitetofetch.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//*[@class='address']" );

foreach ($nodelist as $n){
  $newhtml = $html->saveHtml($n)."\n";
  $newhtml = htmlentities($newhtml);

$items = $html->getElementsByTagName('h1');
}
```

but its not working properly,

How can i do that.

Comment: Can you describe it a little further, the thing you want to accomplish? It's not very clear to me yet.

Comment: I have scraped html <span class="address">....</span>, now whatever tag i select like <h1>xyz</h1>. it will give me "xyz". and if i select <p>pqr</p>. it will give me "pqr".

Comment: Regex isn't preferable to parse html.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458133/php-parse-html-tags) for example gets those tags from an html document via getElementsByTagName().

Comment: and like if i want content of second "p" tag then it will give me "1062 Caracas"

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You may then decide if PHP or JavaScript is suitable...

Comment: If you are trying to render content in webpage, like say color code text by tags, then JS is suitable. Otherwise if you are trying  to send data to a server, then a form is your best bet.

Comment: I need to have only an html tag.

Comment: even getElementsByTagName('h1') is not working.

Comment: try using native DOM   [link](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Please check again as i have edited what i have tried again.

Comment: the above content of html is already coming from scrape using xpath. what i need to do is separate every html tag from that grabbed data.

Comment: I found a solution of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800807/finding-html-tags-in-string, by member @Kilise

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, use a parser instead.
The following snippet loads your `HTML` into the `DOM` and applies xpath queries on it. Obviously, these need to be tweaked a little, but to print out "Dr. Maria Steffens", the following works:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<span class="address">
   <h1>Dr. Maria Steffens</h1>
   <h4>Institute of Medico</h4>
   <h4></h4>
   <h4></h4>
   <p>Sta. Ana, strt PH-501</p>
   <p>1062 Caracas</p>
   <p>France</p>
  <br>
   <p>Telefon: +58-457-2889567</p>
   <p><a href="mailto:plasticsurgery@yahoo.com">plasticsurgery@yahoo.com</a></p>
   <p><a href="http://">www.mysite.com</a></p>
</span>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$headers = $xpath->query("//h1");
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    echo $header->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/gbTGAy).

---

As for your original question, why it didn' work, let's break your expression into its parts:

```
<h1    # match <h1 literally
\s     # followed by one whitespace character (space, tab, newline)
[^>]*  # followed by anything not >, zero or more times
>      # followed by >
(.*)   # anything in that line afterwards
<\/h1> # followed by </h1>
```

Problem is, *there is no whitespace* after `<h1` and `>`, so the expression will fail.

Comment: the content of html is already coming from scrape using xpath. what i need to do is separate every html tag from that grabbed data.

Comment: I think my problem is not too hard, its simply a trick may be, i just need a tag like <p>xyz</p> from html.